# Is there any proof for this simple observation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, metric-spaces

If we consider the Euclidean space $R^3$, it is simply the space where we live. Here we can find only four point such that distance between any two points is a constant. 
[image]
If we consider the Euclidean space $R^2$, it is a $2-D$ plane. There we can find only three points such that distance between any two points is a constant.
[image]
If we consider the Euclidean space $R^1$ it is simply  a line segment. Here we can put only two points such that the previous condition holds.
[image]
My question is can we extend this observations to higher dimensional Euclidean spaces? Can we put $n+1$ points in $R^n$ such that distance between any two points are same(Here I mean the Euclidean distance). If we use a different metric on $R^n$ can we obtain the similar result? Thank you.

Comment: There is also [Proof: Show there is set of $n+1$ points in $\mathbb R^n$ such that distance between any two distinct points is $1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/768046/462)

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I wonder, if you use another metric on $R^n$, can we obtain a similar result?

Comment: @NilanC.Manoj I think so. Depending on your metric, of course, but if it's close to the usual one, then $n$ unit spheres will intersect at discreet points in $\Bbb R^n$ if they are close enough to one another.

Comment: I recommend you read the paper "Geometry for N-Dimensional
Graphics" ftp://www.cs.indiana.edu/pub/hanson/Siggraph01QuatCourse/ggndgeom.pdf

Comment: Just a tiny quiblet. We don't live in $R^3$. If we did, physics wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks :) What do you think, if we use another metric on $R^n$?

Comment: If we use the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ for distinct $x,y$ and $d(x,x)=0$ then distance between any two distinct points are same. So we have more than $n+1$ points. Is there exist a metric which gives less than $n+1$ points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. A sketch of the idea is as follows: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, pick a point and draw an n-sphere of radius $c$ around it. Pick another point on the $n$-sphere and draw another $n$-sphere of radius $c$ around that too. Their intersection forms an $n-1$-sphere. (For instance, the intersection of two 3D spheres is a circle, and the intersection of two circles is two isolated points.) Pick another point along their intersection. Now you have 3 points, and the intersection of n-spheres of radius $c$ around them gives you an $n-2$-sphere. Repeat until you have $n+1$ points and no dimensions left to draw spheres in.