# 3 vectors making equal angles with each other in 3d space?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Say we have three vectors in 3d dimensional space which make equal angles with each of the other vectors. How do we go on about finding the maximum angle they can make with each other?

Ie- If each of those vectors make an angle of ∅ with each other, then are there some limitations or upper bound to the value of ∅.

> More importantly how can we generalise this problem by  having *k* vectors in *N* dimensions making equal angles with every other vector and then finding an upper limit on the angle between them?

For 2 vectors, the answer seems to be 180° since 2 vectors would be coplanar always.

Comment: The vectors have the same angle with each other

Comment: Let me rephrase: What's the maximum value of ø such that 3 vectors in space make an angle of ø with each other.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, ø=120°.

Comment: How did you arrive at that?

Comment: 360°/3. If the three vectors are not coplanar the angle they form is smaller.

Comment: Also idk how much of chemistry you're in touch with but think the tetrahedral structure of methane having 4 H atoms around a C atom and all the C-H bons make an angle of 109° 28' with each other and we can treat those bonds as outward vectors (from C to H). I'm asking is there a limit (or some​ condition) on 'that' angle

Comment: @Aretino Can you guide me to some proof of this fact. Because this would practically solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the three vectors lie in the same plane, then obviously any two of them form an angle of $120°$.

If they are not coplanar, such as unit vectors $\vec{OA}$, $\vec{OB}$ and $\vec{OC}$ in diagram below, let $\angle AOB=\angle BOC=\angle COA=\theta$ and let $H$ be the projection of $O$ onto plane $ABC$. By symmetry we have $\angle AHB=\angle BHC=\angle CHA=\theta'$ and moreover $\theta<\theta'$. To justify the last statement notice for instance that 
$$
AB=2\,OA\sin{\theta\over2}=2\,HA\sin{\theta'\over2},
$$
and $OA>HA$ entails $\theta<\theta'$.

The largest angle is then obtained when all three vectors are coplanar.

[image]

This obviously generalises to $n$ dimensions: you can have at most $n+1$ vectors all making the same angles one another. Their coordinates, and thus the angle they form, can be found as described in [the answers to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714711/how-to-find-n1-equidistant-vectors-on-an-n-sphere).