# Prove or disprove that in an euclidean space $R^n, n \geq 3$ there exist at least $n$ points such that the distance between any two of them is 5

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

I need to prove or disprove that if I have an euclidean space $\mathbb R^n, n \geq 3$ then there are at least $n$ point such that the distance between any two of them is $5$. So far, I tried to use the canonical bases $e_1,e_2,e_3$ for $\mathbb R^3$ in this way.

Lets say $p1=\alpha e_1 + 0e_2 +0e_3 = (\alpha,0,0)$ and, in the same way, let be $p_2=(0,\beta,0), p_2=(0,0,\gamma)$. Then we can define a system of $3$ equations for $3$ variables by imposing that $d(p_1,p_2)=d(p_1,p_3)=d(p_2,p_3)=5$ , where the distance is calculated as $ \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2} $, with $x,y,z$ being the coordinates of my points. So, I got the system:

$\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 25 \to \alpha = \pm 5/\sqrt{2}$

$\alpha^2 + \gamma^2 = 25 \to \alpha = \pm 5 /\sqrt{2}$

$\beta^2 + \gamma^2 = 25 \to \alpha = \pm 5 /\sqrt{2}$

But now my question is: if this is correct, is it enough to prove the statement? And how can I use the induction to extend the results to higher $n$? Those are my first trials to prove stuff and I am not very practical yet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{R}^n\geq3 ?$ Do you mean "$\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $n\geq3$" ?

Comment: Exactly, sorry, I'll correct it immediately

Comment: Just consider $$(1,0,\ldots,0)\\(0,1,\ldots,0)\\ \dots \\ (0,0,\ldots,1)$$ and rescale.

Comment: One can prove a stronger statement: [there exist $n+1$ equidistant points on an $n$-sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/714711).

Comment: The [standard simplex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex) naturally sits in euclidean space of one dimension higher as intersection of the affine hyperplane $x_0 + \cdots + x_n = 1$ and the positive orthant $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. As mentioned above, you can scale this to make the pairwise distance whatever positive quantity that you like.

Answer (score 1):

We can use distance of 1 for simplicity. Multiplying the resulting coordinates by 5 will
scale the distances respectively.

There are $n+1$ points on $\mathbb R^n$ with each pair of points at distance 1 from each
other. This si obvious for $\mathbb R^1$: for example at 0 and 1. We can now use induction
to prove this for arbitrary dimensions.

If we have points $\mathbf p_0, \mathbf p_1, ..., \mathbf p_n \in \mathbb R^n$
fitting the condition we can first
compute their center:

$$ \mathbf c = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \mathbf p_k$$

$\mathbf c$ is the same distance $d$  from each $\mathbf p_k$.

Define a new  point $\mathbf c^\prime \in \mathbb R^{n+1}$ with coordinates

$$ \mathbf c^\prime = (c_1, c_2, ..., c_n, \sqrt{1-d^2}$$

The distance between $\mathbf c^\prime$ and each $\mathbf p_k$ is 1.